# Unwanted gaps between impulses and errorbars in Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I am using impulses to plot the daily maximum temperatures for the last 12 months. The the impulses are 2 pixels wide, and the lenght of the x-axis is set to 2*365=730 pixels. Left margin is set to 60 and right margin to 789. I had not expected any gaps between the impulses, but zooming in shows some unwanted gaps.

Is it possible to avoid this gaps?

```
reset session
$Temperature <<EOD
01.05.2020 7
02.05.2020 8
03.05.2020 9
04.05.2020 13
05.05.2020 10
06.05.2020 11
07.05.2020 17
08.05.2020 8
09.05.2020 6
10.05.2020 10
11.05.2020 14
12.05.2020 16
13.05.2020 12
14.05.2020 7
15.05.2020 11
16.05.2020 18
17.05.2020 20
EOD

set xtics offset 4,0
set format x "%b" timedate
set xrange[time(0)-3600*24*365:time(0)]

set terminal wxt size 820,120
set lmargin at screen 60.0/820
set rmargin at screen 789.0/820
set border back

plot $Temperature u (timecolumn(1,"%d.%m.%Y")):2 w impulses lc "red" lw 2 title ""
```

[image]

The same problem is observed if I use errorbars to plot a bar from the minimum to the maximum temperature:

```
# Bars between min. and max. temperature.
reset session
$AvTempAndDev <<EOD
01.05.2020 3 4
02.05.2020 5 3
03.05.2020 5 4
04.05.2020 8 5
05.05.2020 5 5
06.05.2020 6 5
07.05.2020 10 7
08.05.2020 5 3
09.05.2020 3 3
10.05.2020 5 5
11.05.2020 8 6
12.05.2020 10 6
13.05.2020 8 2
14.05.2020 4 3
15.05.2020 7 4
16.05.2020 11 7
17.05.2020 12 8
EOD

set xtics offset 4,0
set format x "%b" timedate
set xrange[time(0)-3600*24*365:time(0)]
set terminal wxt size 820,120
set lmargin at screen 60.0/820
set rmargin at screen 789.0/820
set border back
set bars 0
plot $AvTempAndDev using (timecolumn(1,"%d.%m.%Y")):2:3 title '' with errorbars pt 0 lw 2 lt rgb "red"
```

[image]

If the bar width is reduced, there will be gaps between all bars, but the gaps on the figure will be wider than the others.
The graph had looked better without the gaps, or if all gaps were equal.

Comment: What do you mean with "gaps"? Could you please show your graph and point to your "gaps"? Maybe you don't want to plot `with impulses` but maybe `with boxes`?

Comment: @Theozh, I do not think boxes will solve the other problem I have added to my questtion (min. and max. temperatures).

Comment: Your screenshot looks like you're zooming in to the pixel level. I'm not sure if you will get aliasing effects because of the rendering. Where did you find that `lw 2` is 2 pixels wide? Haven't found this right away via `help linewidth`.

Comment: @Theozh, I must confess that it was an assumption. If there is 365 bars and the x-axis is 730 pixels  long, then the bars must be 2 pixels wide? But from my figure I see that lw 2 must be more than 2 pixels.

Comment: as I mentioned above and as @Joce explains in his answer, you basically want the plotting style `with boxes` not `with impulses`.But even there you might have the effect that not all boxes might appear the same width on pixel level. I guess this is a rendering thing, because you don't have fractional pixels. With some extra effort, you could "tune" the graph in such a way that the x-axis length is an integer multiple of the boxwidth. But keep in mind the leap years with 366 days.

Comment: Problem solved... or not?

Comment: @theozh - Not as I had hoped. I can "tune" the graph in such a way that gaps are equal. For 365 days, using ```errorbars lw 1``` or ```impulses lw 1``` and a length of the x-axis of 2x365 (```lmargin=60 rmargin=790```), seems to give equal gaps and with ```terminal png size 820, 210```. But it depends on ```lmargin```. Other values of ```lmargin``` gives one or more unequal gaps

Comment: I'm not sure whether I fully understand. So, you want to have a plot which show tiny equal gaps on the pixel level. As I said earlier: Since there are no fractional pixels you have to choose the size of the canvas such that your graph area is exactly n*365 (or n*366) pixels wide. This should be fixed, correct? And the left and right margin as well as the canvas size should be variable depending on the space required for ylabels and ytics, correct? If this is what you are looking for, I guess you have to play some "tricks" and do a replot.

Comment: @theozh - For `d` days, a left margin at `lm` and a right margin at `rm=lm+2*d+1`, gives a nice plot if the impulses are 1 or 2 wide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `d` days, left margin at `lm` and a right margin at `rm=lm+2*d+1`, gives equal gaps between the impulses if the linewidth is 1. If the linewidth is 2, there is no gap and no overlap between the impulses.

```
reset session
myTimeFmt = "%d.%m.%Y"
d = 365                # Number of days

#  Filling $Data with some data for the last d days:
set print $Data
do for [i=1:d] {
      print sprintf("%s %g %g",strftime(myTimeFmt,time(0)-(i-1)*3600*24), 10+8.5*sin(i/72.-1.5))
}

set grid front xtics lt 1 lc rgb "black" lw 1
set xtics 60*60*24*30
set xtics time format "%b 1."
set xrange[time(0)+3600*24-3600*24*(d+1):time(0)]

lm = 60.0                                 #  Left margin
rm = lm+d*2+1                             #  Right margin
w = rm + 40                               #  Terminal width
h = 200                                   #  Terminal height
set terminal wxt size w,h
set lmargin at screen  lm/w
set rmargin at screen rm/w
plot $Data u (timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt)):2 w impulses lc "red" lw 1 title ""
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using `impulses`, which, as the doc says,

> displays a **vertical line** from y=0 to the y value of each  point

So vertical line may look adjacent to one another or not depending on linewidth and magnification. If you change your x-range, you'll see gaps between each line.

The solution is to replace `impulses` by `boxes`.

> In 2D plots the `boxes` style draws a rectangle centered about the given
> x coordinate that extends from the x axis, i.e. from y=0 not from the graph
> border, to the given y coordinate.  The width of the box can be provided in
> an additional input column or controlled by `set boxwidth`.  Otherwise **each
> box extends to touch the adjacent boxes**.

**EDIT:**
If you need boxes that do not start from 0, you can use `with candlesticks` with specification `using x:ymin:ymin:ymax:ymax` and setting first `set boxwidth dx` where `dx` is the width in x-axis units of one box.

Comment: If I make the impulses narrower, there will be a gap betweeen all the impulses, but some of the gaps will be wider then the others. I do not think boxes will solve the other problem I have added to my questtion (min. and max. temperatures).

Comment: Boxes solve the problem that you have first posted. Neither errorbars nor impulses are intended to get contiguous plots, these are made of *lines* whose width is not set according to the distance between your x-axis points.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the style `with boxxyerror`, check `help boxxyerror`.
By the way, the following example shows what your "unwanted gaps" most likely are:
Check the dates of `05.05.2020`, `09.05.2020` and `10.05.2020` minimum and maximum are the same.
What are your expectations on visibility of boxes with heights of zero?

**Code:**

```
### min. max. values with boxxyerror style
reset session

$AvTempAndDev <<EOD
01.05.2020  3   4
02.05.2020  5   3
03.05.2020  5   4
04.05.2020  8   5
05.05.2020  5   5
06.05.2020  6   5
07.05.2020  10  7
08.05.2020  5   3
09.05.2020  3   3
10.05.2020  5   5
11.05.2020  8   6
12.05.2020  10  6
13.05.2020  8   2
14.05.2020  4   3
15.05.2020  7   4
16.05.2020  11  7
17.05.2020  12  8
EOD

set format x "%b %1d" timedate
SecPerHalfDay = 3600*12
set style fill solid 1.0 noborder
set key noautotitle

plot $AvTempAndDev using (timecolumn(1,"%d.%m.%Y")):(($3+$2)/2):(SecPerHalfDay):(($3-$2)/2) w boxxy lc "red"
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Addition:**

As @Joce mentioned, if you want to have the values visible where min. and max. values are identical, it is better to use `with candlesticks`.

You need to add/change the lines:

```
set boxwidth 3600*24
plot $AvTempAndDev using (timecolumn(1,"%d.%m.%Y")):3:3:2:2 w candlesticks lc "red"
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: The block $AvTempAndDev allready contains average value and deviation from average. If I extend the x-axis to 12 months, wxt terminal gives a correct plot, but using `set terminal png size 920,120` will show boxes partly overlapping each other. If I reduce the width of the boxes, the boxes are plotted with both different width and gaps between them.